# SQL match and remove multi-delimited value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out how I can match and delete from on a multi delimited value.

### *For example*

**Table 1**

```
Animal
```

---

```
Dog

Cat 

Cow

Horse
```

**Table 2**

```
Animals
```

---

```
Leopard;fox;hen

Cat;fish

Cow;Horse;hen
```

---

I want to update the values in Table 2 (Animals) so the values in table 1 (Animal) are removed from the varchar value (in Table 2 (Animals)).

Example result:

```
Leopard;fox;hen

fish

hen
```

I'm not sure exactly how to approach this. I'm using SQL Server MGMT studio. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

With the help of a Parse/Split Function and a Cross Apply.

I should note, the logic for the parse can easily be ported into the Cross Apply if you can't use (or want) a UDF.

```
Declare @Table1 table (Animal varchar(50))
Insert Into @Table1 values
('Dog'),
('Cat'),
('Cow'),
('Horse')

Declare @Table2 table (Animal varchar(50))
Insert Into @Table2 values
('Leopard;fox;hen'),
('Cat;fish'),
('Cow;Horse;hen')

;with cte as (
      Select A.Animal
            ,B.*
      From  @Table2 A
      Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.Animal,';') B
      Left Join @Table1 C on B.RetVal=C.Animal 
      Where C.Animal is null
)
Update @Table2 Set Animal=B.NewString
 From  @Table2 A
 Join (
        Select Distinct
               Animal
              ,NewString = Stuff((Select ';' + RetVal From cte Where Animal=A.Animal For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
         From  cte A
      ) B on A.Animal = B.Animal
```

Returns

```
Animal              NewString
Cat;fish            fish
Cow;Horse;hen       hen
Leopard;fox;hen     Leopard;fox;hen
```

The Parse UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
```

Comment: This is really good code, however, I believe it is missing the step of actually updating the values in table 2: as the user stated:

"..... match and delete from on a multi delimited value......"

Comment: @DaniDev See updated answer.  Just injected an UPDATE after the cte

Comment: Nice! Your answer came before I got to finish mine so I just left mine off as yours is clean and thorough. Hopefully @JohnnySemicolon  can accept your answer.

Comment: @DaniDev Thanks for the grin.  Always nice to get a kind word.